# How can I exclude a target folder from deleting, when Publishing an ASP.Net web application?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, deployment, web-deployment, web-publishing

When I try to Publish my web application, It deletes all the existing files in the deployment folder and re-Create everything. I need one folder (say a folder named 'Notes') not to be  deleted.

I can see on the Publish Web wizard to "Excludes files from the app_Data folder". But how can I do it for a folder that I create.

environment:
Visual Studio 2015.

Publish Web with File System as Publish Method.

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try editing the .pubxml file? If you add a "ExcludeFoldersFromDeplyment" property it should work.

Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, it has all the info you need.

Comment: Sadly not works, it still deletes all files and folers, but doesn't copy the excluded folder